# Accounting For Increase In Volume

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance

I'm not very good at statistics but today at work we were in a meeting where manager stood at the top of the room and told us our quality performance in manufacturing our goods had dropped but our number of orders were at record high year on year. Both are measured by KPIs on the percentage scale

I am in the position of having access to all our data as part of my job so we would be dealing with the population and i wanted to do a test using R to maybe demonstrate that some of the drop in performance could be accounted for by the increase in orders

I dont want to be handed the answer as i wont learn anything, but could someone direct me to the appropriate test statistic for this. The idea being if i can account for increase in volumes as being a factor of a certain percentage of the increase in our failure rate, then we could perhaps look at the unknown variance and investigate where it might come from

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply would like to analyze whether quality is related to volume, you could do a regression analysis via glm in R.  Depending on how many years' worth of data you have, you may want to analyze it on a yearly level or a monthly level (or even weekly).  You might want to consider whether there are other factors that may be affecting quality and control for those in the analysis.  If your volume has increased steadily over time, and your quality has decreased steadily for a reason other than volume (for instance, staff morale, new manufacturing procedures, etc.) then it might be difficult to disentangle the cause of low quality, as the data will be confounded.